# Does Android Queue Server Requests if internet is not available?

Tags: java, android, queue, httprequest

Does Android Queue Server Requests if internet is not available?

In my app the user fills out a former and the form then is sent to a .asp form receiver which takes the information and sorts it. Now if there is no internet this can not happen, is there a way to queue the server request , so it will send the next time the user has an internet connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does Android Queue Server Requests if internet is not available?

No.

> Now if there is no internet this can not happen, is there a way to queue the server request , so it will send the next time the user has an internet connection?

Write a queue, perhaps using a file as your backing store. You can monitor the state of connectivity via the `ConnectivityManager`.